# Restrictions OR in hibernate (Java)

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I want rewrite sql query to hibernate criteria and I have this problem.
It is original:

```
if (null != filterGroupIds && !filterGroupIds.isEmpty()) {

                hqueryText += (requereAnd ? " and " : "") + "(";
                requereAnd = true;
                if (filterGroupIds.contains("null")) {
                    hqueryText += " w.crmUser.groupId = null ";

                    filterGroupIds.remove("null");
                    hqueryText += filterGroupIds.isEmpty() ? "" : "or";
                }
                if (!filterGroupIds.isEmpty())
                    hqueryText += " w.crmUser.groupId in (" + StringUtils.join(filterGroupIds.iterator(), ",") + ")";

                hqueryText += ")";
            }
```

It is my criteria:

```
if (null != filterGroupIds && !filterGroupIds.isEmpty()) {

                if (filterGroupIds.contains(Integer.valueOf(-1))) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("crmUser.groupId", null));
                    filterGroupIds.remove(Integer.valueOf(-1));
                    if (!filterGroupIds.isEmpty()) {
                        criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.in("crmUser.groupId", filterGroupIds)));
                    }
                }else {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("crmUser.groupId", filterGroupIds));
                }
            }
```

but my `OR` Restrictions not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting compile time error for
`criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.in("crmUser.groupId", filterGroupIds)));`

as Restrictions.or() takes two criterion values.Recheck your code and pass two criterion object to be compared.